# Html to Excel (xls) File don't accept image Height width Using Codeigniter

Tags: html, excel, codeigniter

I have to try to create and Html to convert xlx file. But there **Img**  tag height not work but tr tag height is work fine . How can I solved this Problem .

**This is my View Page Code**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="main">
         <div id="controller">
            <div class="row">
               <table class="simpleTable" style="margin-top:30px;">
                  <thead>
                     <tr style="background:black;">
                        <th colspan="3" style="color:white;">No</th>
                        <th colspan="6" style="text-align:center;color:white;">Picture</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <?php  foreach($row as $field)  { $reg_id_new =$field->reg_id;  ?>
                     <tr style="height:500px;">
                        <!---------- Tr height is Work Fine  ---------->
                        <th colspan="3"> <?php echo $index; ?>  </th>
                        <th colspan="6" style="text-align:center;"> <img style="height:500px;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>registration/<?php echo $fileInfo;?>">  </th>
                        <!--------- Image height Not Working--------->
                     </tr>
                     <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Donloaded xls file View [image]

Comment: Why are you using a file format that has been superseded since 2007?

Comment: So what do I use

Comment: my page head PHP code

<?php 
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
 //ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Registration.xls");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
?>

Comment: learn [ask] and please don't post code in comments.